# How to retrive Files generated in the past 120 minutes in Linux and also moved to another location

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

For one of my Project, I have a certain challenge where I need to take all the reports generated in a certain path, I want this to be an automated process in "Linux". I know the way how to get the file names which have been updated in the past 120 mins, but not the files directly. Now my requirements are in such a way

1. Take a certain files that have been updated in past 120 mins from the path
   /source/folder/which/contains/files
2. Now do some bussiness logic on this generated files which i can take care of
3. Move this files to 
   /destination/folder/where/files/should/go

I know how to achieve #2 and #3 but not sure of #1. Can someone help me how can i achieve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Define what you mean by "get the files directly". Do you mean copy? Do you mean send it to another program? Do you mean....?

Comment: I need to copy the files to another folder

Answer (score 0):

Write a shell script. Sample below. I haven't provided the commands to get the actual list of file names as you said you know how to do that.

```
#!/bin/sh

files=<my file list>
for file in $files; do
    cp $file <destination_dirctory>
done
```

Comment: let me try this and get back to you